# Is there an efficient way to do remote editing over server using sublime Text 3?

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, iterm2

I am writing some projects and need frequently compile and test on remote machine.

I am not a vim user thou :(

What I end up now is to use  [Fetch](http://fetchsoftworks.com) to browse the project folder and directly open those file using sublime by changing the default editor in Fetch.  It somehow works, but one thing not perfect is that I cannot have a “project” structure in my sublime.

I am wondering anyone has a better way to use Terminal (or iTerm whatsoever) with sublime better.

Comment: Seems like [rsub](https://github.com/henrikpersson/rsub) is a pretty handy tool, but it just works for ST2. Also there's [FSPT plugin for sublime](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) which is commercial.

Comment: also no SSH feature included

Comment: [`rsub`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/rsub) works for both ST2 and ST3 - just install with Package Control.

Comment: @MattDMo what if I don't have sudo right of the server ...

Comment: What does `sudo` have to do with anything? You copy the Ruby or Bash or JavaScript `rmate` script to your server in a directory that's in your `$PATH`, install the plugin in Sublime, type `rmate filename.ext` on the server, and you're good to go.

Comment: The SFTP plugin (not "FSPT") operates over SSH, that's what the "S" stands for. While it is commercial, you can use it without paying, although if you are using it for commercial purposes it is highly recommended that you pay - it's only US$20. That may suit your purposes better.

Comment: @MattDMo hi Matt, sorry to bother, for the `rsub` i basically follow this [post](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2012/09/02/setting-up-rmate-with-sublime-text-for-remote-file-editing-over-ssh/), which is why I mentioned `sudo` does not work.

Comment: There's no need to use `sudo`. That post is only using it to move the file to `/usr/local/bin` and set the executable bit - you can accomplish the same thing by moving it to your personal `bin` directory (assuming you have one) and using `chmod` without `sudo`, since you already own the file.

Comment: Is it correct to assume you're using OS X?

Comment: I am indeed using Mac OS

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is over two years old, I will try to answer it. Maybe it will be helpful for you or others that find it.

First, there is `sshfs`, which you can install via Homebrew or MacPorts. A simple approach would be as following:

```
mkdir -p ~/mnt/server
sshfs user@server.example.com:/path/on/server ~/mnt/server
```

Afterwards, you have the complete folder structure from `server.example.com` locally available at `~/mnt/server`. Make sure you set up SSH keys to avoid entering the user password every time. You can find tutorials on that everywhere on the net.

For servers that only offer FTP access (shared hosting and the like), you can use `curlftpfs` in the same fashion.

To close the connection, simply unmount:

```
umount ~/mnt
```

For a GUI-based approach, you have several options. There is [`Transmit`](https://www.panic.com/transmit/), which features mounting connections as volumes, [`Forklift`](http://www.binarynights.com/forklift/) which is a Finder replacement that can do the same, [`ExpanDrive`](https://www.expandrive.com) and my favorite [`Mountain Duck`](https://mountainduck.io).

If you plan to move lots of data, especially a lot of small files, Mountain Duck performs the best in my testing.

Comment: Probably the best solution I've found so far. Not enough upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TransmitFTP. Any FTP/SFTP/WebDAV/S3 server connection can be mounted as a volume, e.g., `/Volumes/Example`. Then you can browse to it when opening a folder in SB and add to your project like any other directory on your filesystem.